# java image output to zip file using FileSystem is empty

Tags: java, io, zip, java-7

I am currently trying copy an image file to an existing zip file (like appending it). But the output is empty (meaning: The file actually even exists - it is just shown as taking 0 bytes and it cannot be opened / extracted).

Here is my code sample:

```
Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
env.put("create", "true");
Path path = Paths.get("countMap.zip");
java.net.URI uri = java.net.URI.create("jar:" + path.toUri());

try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {

Path nf = fs.getPath("mario.png");

try (OutputStream zos = Files.newOutputStream(nf, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)) {

            Files.createFile(nf, null);

            Files.copy(nf, zos);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

When I debug the java components it looks like everything would be fine. I wonder if there can be some issues with copying a temporary file to the final file destination.

Comment: What is your question specifically?

Comment: question: why is the file empty instead of being the file I wanted to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got the problem.

```
Files.copy(nf, zos);
```

didn't work at all. So I tried using streams:

```
final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;

while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
zos.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
zos.close();
```

which did not work as well. But funnily (and kind of House M.D. wise :-)) I just had a friend with a similar problem. 
In his case, a file writer did not output anything - or half. Weird, of course. But his problem was, that he forgot to close the stream.

So I looked at my code - but everything's fine there. But then I started trying funny solutions and just removed the close() - AND IT WORKED! Weird, of course. And not at all predictable. But at least my case is solved now. Does anyone think that may be a bug in JAVA? And maybe know how to report it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try (untested):

```
Path image = ...;
Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
env.put("create", "true");
Path path = Paths.get("countMap.zip");

try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(path.toUri(), env)) {
    Path nf = fs.getPath("/mario.png");
    Files.copy(image , nf );
 }
```